# Accessing a datasource from an OSGi bundle

Tags: spring, apache-camel, osgi, apache-servicemix

I have a blueprint file containing a datasource deployed to Apache ServiceMix. I was able to query the datasource from Apache Karaf console. How can I access this datasource from a Camel Spring-DM bundle application? This is my blueprint file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
   <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="URL"/>
        <property name="user" value="USER"/>
        <property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    </bean>
  <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" id="ds">
    <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/ds"/>
    </service-properties>
  </service>
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the DataSource as an OSGi service. In spring dm this is osgi:reference, in blueprint it would be reference.

```
<reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

You can then inject the DataSource for example into the SqlComponent.

As an example see a fix I did for [this camel route](https://github.com/cschneider/blog/blob/master/camel/camel-transactional-database-transfer/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/beans.xml#L17-L19). This is blueprint but it is almost the same for spring dm.

```
<bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you provide me an example of how to inject the DataSource. I'm unable to resolve the DataSource in my application bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Using Hibernate as JPA provide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">   

     <persistence-unit name="jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
         <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
         <jta-data-source>osgi:service/jdbc/ds</jta-data-source>

     ...

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```